# Home domain selection during UNIX-like OS install?

Tags: networking

Whenever I install a UNIX-like system, it asks for domain.

For a little home network, what should I choose?

Like ex.: foobarmachine.lan?

Or is the "lan" domain used publicly? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is, unfortunately, no "reserved" domain for private networks. Some people use `.local`, but this causes conflicts with zeroconfig addresses (which may or may not be a problem for you). And generally creating a TLD like `.lan` is considered bad practice due to `.lan` not being reserved (and thus the potential for it to begin conflicting if something adopts `.lan` in the future).

It should be possible to install most *nixes without specifying a domain. You can simply leave it blank. If you actually need to have a domain for the machine for some reason, the suggested course of action is to register a domain like "foobar.net" and use that for your lan domain... this effectively reserves the domain so there can be no conflicts.

Comment: hey, thanks for the "leave it blank" idea :) will try it next time!